Known changes to NSURLSessionDataTask from iOS 16 to iOS 17?
I've tried to find out if there were any significant behavioral changes for NSURLSessionDataTask between iOS versions 16 and 17, but have not found any answers.
I'm having an issue where I'm performing a 'POST' request to an endpoint. On iOS 16, I'm getting a 400 status code, on iOS 17, a 200. There are no changes in the source code or the endpoint being accessed.
NSURLSessionDataTask is being configured with [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] and the request Content-Type is set to application/json
Are there any known changes in iOS versions that can explain this behavior?

Unlikely, your best bet is to check the server logs. When I encountered similar issues in the past, it was usually a simple mistake like forgotten #available directive or a more subtle difference, e.g. iPhone vs iPad.

Also check the response body from the server. It should tell you why there was a 400 response
